# error running google endpoint api explorer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I attempt to load the Google Cloud Endpoint Explorer, I get a blank page.  If I load the local page that it is wrapping, I get the following NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.handleExplorer(RestApiServlet.java:143)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
...
```

My .api and .discovery files are generated.  When I call my discovery doc (/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/XXX/v1/rest), it appears in the browser.

I am not sure what to do from here.  Can anyone offer a suggestion?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **REALLY** hate to say this but I was having the issue in Chrome but I was able to get it to load in IE when I tried.

This blank screen issue was due to the fact that it was mixed content.  It was not allowing the local script to run on the SSL page it redirected to.  The little alert icon in Chrome was not obvious to me until I started searching the web for possible mixed-content issues.

Comment: Same here. API didn't load in Chrome or FF, but worked fine in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser file cache and see if the issue clears up. No need to clear cookies or anything else depending on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https to visit explorer page, please use http and see whether it will work.

For example, [http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer]